# <SQL>How to change the size of VARCHAR2 of the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I googled it enough but for some reason, mine doesnt work.

the column name is **CD**. type is **VARCHAR2(10Byte)**

Table name is **TB_POT_ECD_CD**

I want to change the size of column to **VARCHAR2(100Byte)**

```
ALTER TABLE TB_POT_ECD_CD MODIFY(CD VARCHAR2(100))
```

didn't work. Can anyone look at it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Then I do not get why `modify` doesn't work. It should in versions >=9i. Do you get any kind of error or what?

Comment: I get ORA-00942. Table or View does not exist.
Could it be because there is data in the column?

Comment: I've provided few possible solutions to get your `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY` to work. It was too big for a comment

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You may `remove` that column and `add` it again with new size

```
ALTER TABLE TB_POT_ECD_CD 
DROP COLUMN CD

ALTER TABLE TB_POT_ECD_CD 
ADD CD VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: But the column should be empty in order to remove it. correct?

Comment: I think no. Am not pretty sure. Let me check and get back you

Comment: its possible to drop the column even if it contains data. Check this fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db4bf/1

Comment: There is absolutely no need to drop a column in order to make it larger, even if it contains data.

Comment: friends i said `You may` remove and add. If the other thing is working i said an alternative solution which may help him. There is nothing to worry this much.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible to modify a column containing data, including changing its size; the one exception is that we cannot make a column smaller than the largest value existing in the column **(1)**.

This is the syntax ...

```
alter table TB_POT_ECD_CD modify cd varchar2(100 byte)
/
```

... and here is a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5082d/1) too.

**(1)** This is true of 11gR2 and perhaps earlier versions; in older versions of Oracle we could only shrink empty columns.  Thanks to @StanMcgeek for pointing this out to me.

---

> "I get ORA-00942. Table or View does not exist."

That is a problem with your SQL.  Probably you've misspelled the table, or you're trying to run the query from the wrong schema.

Comment: I believe you can make it smaller if the size is big enough to contain current data

Comment: @StanMcGeek - you're right.  That didn't use to be the case, but I've just tried and it's certainly true of 11gR2,  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you said on comments under your question you get `ORA-00942` on `ALTER TABLE` query. There are few solutions I can think of:

- Try to specify the owner/schema in the query
- You have somehow corrupted entry in statement cache: try this query `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;` and then your `ALTER TABLE` with `MODIFY` again
- Check wether your table is an actual table, not, for example, a synonym to a table in a different schema